# Stop Python adding " " when reading some .csv files

Tags: python-3.x

I have a number of .csv files which I am opening in Python3. Some open fine and the script runs fine, others I get the below error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 5547: invalid start byte
```

If I tell Python to ignore errors as below

```
dataset = open('data.csv', 'r', errors='inore')
```

The script then runs but it adds quotation marks around each column header in the .csv e.g.

```
"No.","Time","Source","Destination"
```

How can I open the .csv without the quotation marks, as per the others that already do this e.g. below

```
 No.,Time,Source,Destination
```

I have tried this running on Linux Mint 18.3 with Python 3.6.4 and Mac OSx with Python 3.6.3 and get same results on both. I do not have a windows PC to try.

Comment: Why would open change file contents?

Comment: I'm not suer if it is or whether it is the way the file was previously saved. I thought open() handled utf-8 fine

Answer (score 1):

try to strip the string mate :)

```
a ="\"a\""
print(a.strip("\""))
```

or replace the "

```
a.replace("\"", "")
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. What I find strange is that I checked the encoding of two files (one which works and the other that does the above) and they both say us-ascii.  I can't figure out why the script treats two files differently.

Comment: @Bat, can you share the two files in your question?